# general speed issues when comparing strings using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

Is there anyway of improving the speed / efficiency of this method? It is called tens of thousands of time in my code, and is slowing down the system I am developing.

Basically, 'Field' has a 'Name' and a 'Value' and I need to check if it matches the name/value of the corresponding property in my class. Field.Value may also be a regular expression. I imagine the regex is slowing things down a bit.

```
    private bool FieldMatch(Field field)
    {
        var propValue = GetPropertyValue(field.Name);
        var regEx = new Regex(field.Value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var stringMatch = string.Compare(propValue, field.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase )
        return (stringMatch == 0) || regEx.IsMatch(propValue);
    }
```

Comment: Does the same `field.Value` get passed in multiple times?  In the past, I've found that constructing the `Regex` object can be slow, so if you can cache instances of it for a given expression it may improve the performance

Comment: So I could precompile the RegEx within the instance of the Field class, perhaps?

Comment: You might replace the value by a regex, that will hence be created only once. Or have a cache or Regexes, if the values won't vary that much.

Comment: If it's never, or rarely, the same - you could move it's construction to after the check for `stringMatch == 0` and only construct it if needed

Comment: Precompiling will only move the performance issue elsewhere.  You need to create a cache of regex objects for given strings, assuming that there are enough that are the same to make it worthwhile

Comment: Each field.Value will potentially be evaluated hundreds of times though. I've actually just switched to the static RegEx and it's helped substantially.

Comment: Ok, yes in that case precompiling or a cache will definitely help

Comment: An afterthought - it is probably still worth saving the initial construction until after the first time `stringMatch == 0` is false for a given `Field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions to this issue.

One is to add a pre-compiled Regex to the Field class like so:

```
public class Field
{

    public string Name { get; set; } // Should ultimately be an enum.

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Regex RegexValue
    {
        get {
            return _regexValue ?? (_regexValue = 
                new Regex(Value, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
        }
    }

    private Regex _regexValue;

}

private bool FieldMatch(Field field)
{
    var propValue = GetPropertyValue(field.Name);
    var stringMatch = string.Compare(propValue, field.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    return (stringMatch == 0) || field.RegexValue.IsMatch(propValue);
}
```

The other is to use the static Regex like so:

```
  private bool FieldMatch(Field field)
    {
        var propValue = GetPropertyValue(field.Name);
        var stringMatch = string.Compare(propValue, field.Value,                     StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        return (stringMatch == 0) || Regex.IsMatch(propValue, field.Value);
    }
```

Which one is quickest depends on the scale of the system, but both are a very good improvement over the previous solution

Comment: +1.  Looks good.  As you say, you'll need to do some benchmarks to find out which is more appropriate.  I suspect the first, as you say the same `Field` is used potentially hundreds of times